# Linear programming: modelling a transportation problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have a transportation problem with a twist-- I have a set number of managers and a set number of stores (where there are way more stores than managers), and I'm trying to match the managers to stores. The twist is that each manager can have up to a certain number of stores (constraint), and no two managers share the same store. The goal is to minimise the distance between the manager and each store s/he manages. I haven't been able to figure out how to model this problem, or rather if it is even possible to formulate this problem into a linear programming model. Please let me know!

Comment: Is this not better thought of as an assignment problem rather than a transportation problem? You will need multiple rows for each manager to represent the multiplicity of stores that can be managed by each. To keep the problem balanced you will also need dummy stores (representing managers not getting a store assignment). The solution is likely to be highly none unique.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{ij}$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if manager $i$ is assigned to store $j$.

You want to minimize the total distance after assignment:
$$
\sum_{i,j}d_{ij}x_{ij}
$$
subject to :

- A manager $i$ cannot have more than $S_i$ stores :
  $$
  \sum_{j}x_{ij} \le S_i\quad \forall i
  $$
- No two managers share the same store :
  $$
  \sum_{i}x_{ij} =1 \quad \forall j
  $$
- Variables are binary :
  $$
  x_{ij}\in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i,j
  $$